# Reopen Mysql Connection in Python

Tags: python, mysql

just wanna ask how do you reopen the connection after closing it?

i have this script

```
cursor.execute(add_data, dummy_data)
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='',
                                password ='',host='',
                              database='')
cursor = cnx.cursor()

add_data = insert statement
dummy_data = dictionary of data


cursor.execute(add_data, dummy_data)

cnx.commit()
cnx.close()
```

After inserting one set of values i cannot insert anymore.

This is the error :
"**OperationalError: 2055: Lost connection to MySQL server at system error 9: Bad file descriptor**"

thanks in advance!

Comment: Normally, we close it after we've done all the inserts/updates/selects/...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a new connection object after you close

```
cnx2 = mysql.connector.connect(user='',
                                password ='',host='',
                              database='')
```

but why would you close the connection? you should close the cursor and keep the connection open for all operations.

I would define an open connection function and a close connection function that I will call at begginning and end of program respectively.

Comment: but python doesnt have an open connection function unlike other languages, so i just need to declare a new one after closing the cursor?

Comment: yes that is what I meant actually the `connect` function is the `open`

Comment: you're welcome. If you think this answered your question well, please accept it and/or upvote. Thanks you!